# Como verificar se uma checkbox em um form foi selecionado através de outro form?

Tags: c#, checkbox

Quero verificar se em um form foi selecionado um checkbox,pois estou trabalhando com diversos form.

Utilizando o seguinte código,não funciona :

```
frmPrincipal f = new frmPrincipal();

 if (f.chkNotificacao.Checked == true)
    {                       
       f.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Notificação",
"Um novo usuário foi cadastrado.", ToolTipIcon.Info);
    }
```

Caso eu coloque deste jeito para testar,ele funciona,mas ele estará sempre deixando como true :

```
  frmPrincipal f = new frmPrincipal();

         f.chkNotificacao.Checked = true;

         if (f.chkNotificacao.Checked == true)
            {                       
               f.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Notificação", 
"Um novo usuário foi cadastrado.", ToolTipIcon.Info);
            }
```

Há algum outro modo de fazer uma verificação de um checkbox de outro form ? Pois preciso fazer a verificação.

Caso seja criado um novo usuário irá verificar se esta checkbox foi selecionada,para disparar uma notificação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisei em outros lugares para ver se encontrava a solução,e acabei encontrando,vou postar aqui o código para ajudar as pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema que eu tive.

Criei um método para fazer a verificação da checkbox para ver se ela estava sendo selecionada ou não.

Código :

```
  Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
  public bool IsCheckboxChecked
  {
     get { return frm2.chkNotificacoes.Checked; }
  }

  if(IsCheckBoxChecked.Equals(true)) {
   //funcionou
  }
  else {
  //não funcionou
  }
```

Este é o código que eu fiz para poder fazer a verificação e funcionou normalmente.